# How can I select the maximum value in NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, max, fluent

I need to get maximum page order from database:

```
int maxOrder = GetSession.Query<Page>().Max(x => x.PageOrder);
```

The above works if there are rows in the database table, but when table is empty I'm getting:

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: item
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Session.Query<Page>().Max(x => (int?)x.PageOrder)
```

Note the cast (I'm assuming PageOrder is an int)

Comment: This will throw `ArgumentOutOfRange` exception with NHibernate v3.3.1.* in case there are no `Page` records in the db

Answer (score 15):

In the way you are doing it is normal to get an exception as the enumerable, that the `GetSession.Query<Page>()` returns, is empty (because the table is empty as you mentioned).

The exception that you should be getting is: Sequence contains no elements.
The exception you mention in your question is because the item variable (which is irrelevant with the NHiberanate query you list above) is null (line 54 assigns the item property to null).

A safer way to get the max from a property in a table would be the following:

```
var max = GetSession.CreateCriteria<Page>()
                .SetProjection(Projections.Max("PageOrder"))
                .UniqueResult();
```

or using QueryOver with NHibenrate 3.0:

```
var max = GetSession.QueryOver<Page>()
      .Select(
            Projections
               .ProjectionList()
               .Add(Projections.Max<Page>(x => x.PageOrder)))
      .List<int>().First();
```

If the table is empty you will get max = 0

Comment: thank u a lot! is it possible to use strongly typed version of it? :)

Comment: You can use QueryOver if you are using NHibernate 3.0. I have edited my answer to include a version with QueryOver.

Comment: @tolism7 The QueryOver version did not work for me with an empty table. I would have expected the behavior you describe, but the call to List<int> throws an Exception instead... However, Diego's answer works fine for me and is also shorter :)

Comment: @MartinKlinke Well, its been more than 3 years since I gave that answer and a few things might have changed in NHibernate since then. In the version I tested this it worked fine but I am happy that you have found an answer here even if it wasn't mine ;-)

Comment: The exception happens because if there are no DB records then the type that the query results in is int?, not int. If you modify the code to take this into account it's possible to get it to work, you just have to do a bunch of null checking which isn't very nice.

Answer (score 8):

If you are having problems with the QueryOver example by tolism7 (InvalidCastException), here's how I got it working:

```
var max = session.QueryOver<Page>()
    .Select(Projections.Max<Page>(x => x.PageOrder))
    .SingleOrDefault<object>();

return max == null ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(max);
```